# Get random background-image from this div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get a random image with from example: `id="myid"` with javascript or jQuery? Is it possible? Thanks

```
<div id="myid" class="myclass">    
  <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/768eec43.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>
  <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/a79e6b78.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>  
  <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/27570903.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>     
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You should really have a look at SO rules before posting homework ;)

Comment: yes, this is possible. But when you say random image, do you mean select any random image from the internet, or do you mean select a random image (ie shuffle the order) of the images you currently have?

Comment: to be honest, I'm new to this field, I don't know moch about script, I jus have start to leran somthing from internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you need to access the url value of the style attribute of the many spans, and want to select one of the url by random.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var spans = $('#myid span[style]');
  var arr = [];
  spans.each(function(i,d){
    var str = $(d).attr('style');
    var url = str.substring(str.indexOf('url')+4,str.indexOf(";")-1);
    arr.push(url);
  });
  
  var r = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length);
  
  console.log(arr[r]);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myid" class="myclass">    
  <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/768eec43.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>
  <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/a79e6b78.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>  
  <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/27570903.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>     
</div>
```

Comment: how I have say before, im new, so i see your code works but, I still need help how to display id on background? Thanks again

Comment: can you show me how I can do it, to change every page load not on button click thanks again

Comment: @Leo I have updated my code to run after page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following way. This will select random images using jquery.

```
$(function () {
  var images = [
    'image-01.jpg',
    'image-02.jpg',
    'image-03.jpg'
  ];
  $('.imageClass').css(
    { 
      'background-image': 'url(Styles/Default/Images/ImageLocation/' + 
        images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)] + ')' 
    }
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var selector=$("#myid > span")
var imageURL=[]
for(var i=0;i<selector.length;i++)
{
var bg=$("#myid > span")[i].style["backgroundImage"];
var startIndex=bg.indexOf("(");
var EndIndex=bg.indexOf(")");
imageURL.push(bg.substring(startIndex+1,EndIndex));
}
var randomURL = imageURL[Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURL.length)];
console.log(randomURL)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myid" class="myclass">    
  <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/768eec43.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>
  <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/a79e6b78.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>  
  <span class="AvGbtn" style="background-image: url(/uploads/articles/27570903.jpg); background-size: 100% 100%;" rel="nofollow"></span>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oke, let's try to get you started with this 3-liner:

```
// get all elements with images with jQuery
var imgs = $(".AvGbtn");
// get a random number from 1 to 3
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
// I put this in console but here you got the URL to random one from images, do as you like
console.log($(imgs[rand]).css('background-image'));
```

Rest you need to specify, what to do once we got URL (I decided to write it in console). And it would be in your best interest to review what I wrote above and play with it.

Here are some ideas:

- Make it X images long and try to fix the logic so it works with X
  items with pictures.
- Display image in the div below other ones
- Display sequence of 10 URLs chosen this way.
- Do something with URL
  obtained etc..

P.S. Don't forget to include jQuery for this to work.

P.P.S. You can play in JS fiddle I made with this example if you like:
https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/978128/

Comment: Thank you very mouch for your help

Comment: Sure thing. Just please, remember, homework is meant to be done by oneself. Even if you have no desire what so ever to become developer one day, you can still develop yourself mentally ba solving it, programming is mostly logic, order and to be honest good Google skills. All 3 are extremely beneficial in most areas of work these days. Play with it a bit, spend some time developing brain power, you will thank me later ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample fiddle for you.

https://jsfiddle.net/voqfnzus/7/

Javascript

```
var images = [
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/1020315/pexels-photo-1020315.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350", 
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/207171/pexels-photo-207171.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940",
  "https://images.pexels.com/photos/719609/pexels-photo-719609.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940"
]

function showNextRandomImage() {
  var nextRandomImage = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
  $("#AvGbtn").css("background-image", "url(" + nextRandomImage + ")");
}

$("#btn").click(function() {
  showNextRandomImage();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  showNextRandomImage();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="myid" class="myclass">
  <span id="AvGbtn" style="" rel="nofollow"></span>
</div>

<button id="btn">
  Change
</button>
```

CSS

```
#AvGbtn {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 12px;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help